# XML full file reading C#

Tags: c#, xml

So I have a code that reads partially into an XML document, precenting me with the first block of results which is great, but I have a file containing multiple blocks of the same code & my program seems to quit after the first.

Here's the code:

```
string path = "data//handling.meta";
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");//.ToArray();
var query = from i in items
            select new 
            {
                HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"),
                Mass = (decimal?)i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value"), 
                InitialDragCoeff = (decimal?)i.Element("fInitialDragCoeff").Attribute("value"), 
                PercentSubmerged = (decimal?)i.Element("fPercentSubmerged").Attribute("value"), 
                DriveBiasFront = (decimal?)i.Element("fDriveBiasFront").Attribute("value"), 
                InitialDriveGears = i.Element("nInitialDriveGears").Attribute("value")
            }
string test = ("{0} - {1}" + query.First().HandlingName + query.First().Mass + query.First().InitialDragCoeff);
richTextBox1.Text = test;
```

Here's the XML Document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<CHandlingDataMgr>
  <HandlingData>
    <Item type="CHandlingData">
      <handlingName>Car1</handlingName>
      <fMass value="140000.000000" />
      <fInitialDragCoeff value="30.000000" />
      <fPercentSubmerged value="85.000000" />
      <vecCentreOfMassOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
      <vecInertiaMultiplier x="1.000000" y="1.000000" z="1.000000" />
      <fDriveBiasFront value="1.000000" />
      <nInitialDriveGears value="1" />
    </Item>
    <Item type="CHandlingData">
      <handlingName>Car2</handlingName>
      <fMass value="180000.000000" />
      <fInitialDragCoeff value="7.800000" />
      <fPercentSubmerged value="85.000000" />
      <vecCentreOfMassOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
      <vecInertiaMultiplier x="1.000000" y="1.300000" z="1.500000" />
      <fDriveBiasFront value="0.200000" />
      <nInitialDriveGears value="6" />
    </Item>
 </HandlingData>
</CHandlingDataMgr>
```

As shown, there's multiple handling Name's. The CSharp code above does work, but only for the first block & I'm wondering how to make it read the same values from the different handling name.

I have tried :

```
if (query.First().HandlingName == "Car2")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Car 2 found");
}
```

but since the message box never appeared, I assume this code doesn't read the hole file?

I'm hoping for output like this:

```
Name: Car 1 
Mass: 140000.000000
InitialDragCoeff: 30.000000

Name: Car 2
Mass: 180000.000000
InitialDragCoeff: 7.800000
```

My problem in a 'nut shell' : Program does not see Car 2

Any help would be really appreciated, as I've tried many solutions & read many pages regarding XML today

Comment: Please use correct code - for a start a `select new` needs braces and you seem to be missing the end of the LINQ comprehension expression.

Comment: Your query contains all the cars. query.First() will give you first car (which is obviously Car1 - by order of your xml). If you're searching for Car2 you should do something like var car2 = query.First(c => c.HandlingName == "Car2");

Comment: ^ Returns 'input string not in correct format'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
string test = ("{0} - {1}" + query.First().HandlingName + query.First().Mass 
         +  query.First().InitialDragCoeff);
```

that's only ever going to get you the first element, because that's what you asked for.

I think you probably want to loop:

```
foreach (var item in query) {
  var s = "{0} - {1}" + item.HandlingName + query.item.Mass 
         +  item.InitialDragCoeff
  // …
}
```

Comment: How would I then make the foreach loop display into richtextbox1 ?

Comment: @DannyNichols Use a `StringBuilder` to incrementally build the string as you loop, and use its `ToString()` to extract the content to pass to the rich text box.

Comment: I've only been studying CSharp for 6months (self-taught), I got no idea how to make a stringbuilder work inside a foreach loop :( - Please edit your answer to include such code?

Comment: Wow, didn't realize how easy stringbuilder's were to use. Thanks a lot for your reply, my code is finally working :D